# PHP Insert table into database

Tags: php, insert, html-table

I have a database table that I created from a .csv file. I used php to edit the content to match a new table on my database. I now need to INSERT that new table into the new database. I added form tags around the table and a submit button, and when I submit it I only get 1 or 2 random rows of the table. I am guessing that I might need a while or a for loop, but I cant figure out how to write it. Any assistance would be appreciated.

This is the code to post to the db

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$mr = $_POST['mr'];
$mrs = $_POST['mrs'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$marital_status = $_POST['marital_status'];


$query = "INSERT INTO import_template(first_name, last_name, marital_status) VALUES('{$mr}', '{$last_name}', '{$marital_status}')";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

if(!$result){
    die("QUERY FAILED " . mysqli_error($connection));
}
if(!$connection){
echo "We are NOT connected";
}

$query = "INSERT INTO import_template(first_name, last_name, marital_status) VALUES('{$mrs}', '{$last_name}', '{$marital_status}')";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

  if(!$result){
    die("QUERY FAILED " . mysqli_error($connection));
}
if(!$connection){
echo "We are NOT connected";
}
}
```

This is what the dynamic table looks like I only added the input to the first few to test, I haven't done the rest yet.

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='mr' value='$mr'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='last_name' value='$last_name'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='marital_status' value='$marital_status'></td>";
echo "<td>{$birthday}</td>";
echo "<td>Adult</td>";
echo "<td>{$anniversary}</td>";
echo "<td>{$mr_cell_phone}</td>";
echo "<td>{$home_phone}</td>";
echo "<td>{$mr_email}</td>";
echo "<td>{$street}</td>";
echo "<td>{$city}</td>";
echo "<td>{$state}</td>";
echo "<td>{$zip}</td>";
echo "<td></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='mrs' value='$mrs'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='last_name' value='$last_name'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='marital_status' value='$marital_status'></td>";
echo "<td></td>";
echo "<td>Adult</td>";
echo "<td>{$anniversary}</td>";
echo "<td>{$mrs_cell_phone}</td>";
echo "<td></td>";
echo "<td>{$mrs_email}</td>";
echo "<td></td>";
echo "<td></td>";
echo "<td></td>";
echo "<td></td>";
echo "<td></td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: what you've tried yet?

Comment: I have done a normal $query INSERT. My table is dynamic and is about 500 rows with about 10 columns, each row has the same name (name='example') so when I run the insert I only get 1 or 2 random rows. I have no idea how to write a loop to do this, I am working on trying to count the rows and then use that in a for or while loop

Comment: Can you update your question with tried script?

Comment: I updated the question, all that is echoed there will be looped through as long as it is pulling data from one of the db tables, again it is about 500 rows worth. I think that I need to loop the insert query some how

Comment: These two rows are in a loop? and one thing you have used same name in  form element name and the result of this last one will overwrite previous value.

Comment: Ya thats the problem, I had to create the table from a while loop coming from a different table on the db. Is there a way to create a loop that will insert every time it completes a row?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this. I have taken three fields such as task,agent and note.You can add as per your table rows:

**main.php**

```
<form id="first" action="insert_values.php"  method="post">


<table>
<tr>
<td>Task</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="task">
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Agent</td>
    <td>
   <input type="text" name="agent">
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Note</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Note"></td>
    </tr>

    </table>
     <input type="submit" value="save" name="save">
    </form>
```

**insert_values.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting( error_reporting() & ~E_NOTICE );
session_start();
include 'connect.php';


 $task=$_POST['task'];
  $agent=$_POST['agent'];


  $Note=$_POST['Note'];




$result=mysql_query("insert into table_name(task,agent,t_note) values('$task','$agent','$Note')");



if($result)
{   
$msg="Insert Successfully!!";
echo "<script>alert('Insert Successfully');document.location='main.php'</script>";
?>

<?php
}
else
{

$errmsg=" Insert not success!!";
      echo "<script>alert('Insert Not Successfully');document.location='main.php'</script>";

}

?>
```

Comment: Thats sort of what I have, how would you do that if that table row was multiplied? So the name='' that each field is using is on each row. How would I loop through all the rows as they all have the same names, just different values?

Comment: I didnt understand what you are trying to say...u want to insert the details in the db or you want to display the data at the browser?

Comment: I want to insert the data into my db. My table is dynamic and has data from another db table in it.

Comment: the table looks sort of like this 
            echo "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='first_name' value='$first_name'></td>";
            echo "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='last_name' value='$last_name'></td>";
            echo "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='email' value='$email'></td>"; So all the information that i want to insert is different but has the same name on each row. When I do a normal insert into the db, it only takes 1 or 2 of the rows